# Video View in listview stops evrytime I scroll list

Tags: android

i am using a videoview in listview.but every time i scroll list,the app either crashes(giving windowManager bad token exception) or doesnt respond and the video being played also stops.
how to pause video when the whole view is scrooled.I am not talking about scroll listener i want the video to be paused when the whole videoview is scrolled.
here's my code:-

```
public class Virtual_open_house_videos_activity extends Activity{
    TextView video_uploading_date,text_address;
    ListView list;
    String date,address;
    VideoView video;
    ArrayList<String>videos_list=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Boolean> playingStatus;
    ArrayList<VideoView> mediaController;
    ImageView img_play_vid=null,img_dislike_vid=null,back_button_01;
    Custom custom_adapter=new Custom();
    String getvideo;
    MediaController media_Controller;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_virtual_open_house_videos);

        init();
        getVal();
        setVal();
        setListener();

    }
    void setListener(){
        back_button_01.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });

    }
    void init()
    {   
        video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.property_video_listview);
        back_button_01=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.back_button_01);
        video_uploading_date=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.video_uploading_date);
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.videos_list);
        img_play_vid=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_play_vid);
        img_dislike_vid=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_dislike_vid);
        playingStatus=new ArrayList<Boolean>();
        mediaController=new ArrayList<VideoView>();
        text_address=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.address_text);
        list.setAdapter(custom_adapter);

    }
    void getVal()
    {
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        date=intent.getExtras().getString("date");
        address=intent.getExtras().getString("address");
        Log.v("adress check",address);
        videos_list=intent.getStringArrayListExtra("video");
        Log.v("video list check", videos_list+"");

    }
    void setVal(){
        video_uploading_date.setText(date);
        videos_list.add(address);
        //al.addAll(videos_list);

    }
    class Custom extends BaseAdapter{

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return videos_list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return videos_list.get(arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.v("entering adapter", "adapter entered correctly");
            View view=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_inflate_virtual_video, null);
            final ImageView img_play_vid=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.img_play_vid);
            final ImageView img_dislike_vid=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.img_dislike_vid);
            TextView porp_address=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.address_text);
            porp_address.setText(address);
            getvideo=videos_list.get(arg0);
            video=(VideoView)view.findViewById(R.id.property_video_listview);
            Log.v("address check", address);

            /*view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent=new Intent(Virtual_open_house_videos_activity.this,Fsbo_video_play_activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("video", videos_list.get(arg0));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });*/
            playVid();
            img_play_vid.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Log.v("reaching code", "code reached");
                    if(playingStatus.get(arg0)==false){
                        //property_video.start();   
                        Log.v("playing status at postion "+arg0,""+playingStatus.get(arg0));
                        mediaController.get(arg0).start();
                        playingStatus.set(arg0, true);
                    }

                    else{
                        Log.v("playing status at postion "+arg0,""+playingStatus.get(arg0));
                        mediaController.get(arg0).pause();;

                        playingStatus.set(arg0, false);
                    }

                }
            });
            return view;    



    }
    public void playVid() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.v("function called", "crashing here");
        MediaController mc=new MediaController(getApplicationContext());
        video.setMediaController(new MediaController(getApplicationContext()));
        mc.setMediaPlayer(video);
        mc.setAnchorView(video);
        Log.v("getting video", getvideo);
        Uri video_uri = Uri.parse(getvideo);
        video.setVideoURI(video_uri);
        playingStatus.add(false);
        Log.v("playing status", playingStatus+"");
        mediaController.add(video);
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I see here is that your `getView` method recreates the view every time it is supposed to recycle an old view, causing the old media player to keep on playing or crash when destroyed.

Instead, you should use **ViewHolder** technique to properly recycle your views and probably stop the video once an old instance of media player is retrieved in `getView`.

For more info, read [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-listview-optimizations) and [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html).

Comment: thanks for your suggession,i'll try that and let you know whether it worked or not